# Capacitors filled with parallel $n$ dielectrics

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

I'll be brief. In cases where we have a capacitor filled with an $n$-amount of different dielectrics, each and everyone one right next to the other, is it okay to re-think the problem as having n capacitors connected in series? where each one of those new capacitors is filled with only one dielectric.

Then I could just find the capacity of every one of the "new" capacitors and finally calculate the equivalent capacity.

I'll leave a picture of the problem I need to solve, and how I wanted to solve it using this methodology. (The blank spaces between the plaques and the blue dielectric would be air)

[image: Problem]

Comment: Equation 10.3 seems to say yes https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_10.html

Comment: I think you mean "(D-t)" not "2(D-t)".

Comment: I wrote "2(D-t)" because the original capacitor has 2 blank spaces of length D-t. Instead of re-expressing the problem as 3 new capacitors (2 filled with air and 1 filled with the blue dielectric) connected in series, I just "combined" the 2 blank spaces and thought of them as 1. Please let me know if that's incorrect, but I think the math ends up being the same for both ways

Comment: @LucasDiPa   That's not what the picture you posted shows.   The total "empty" distance in the picture is "D-t".    Each space in the single cap on the left would be "1/2 (D-t)"   (Presuming the dielectric is centered between the plates)

Comment: Oh, I see it now, you are right. What a foolish mistake, thank you.